# passing list collection to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have

View:

```
  <div class="partialContents comiclist" data-url="@Url.Action("LoadAlphabetBook2", "book", new { delimiters = "#;;;0;;;1;;;2;;;3;;;4;;;5;;;6;;;7;;;8;;;9", keywords = "0 - 9", startLetter = "0", categoryIds = new List<int> { Model.categoryId } })">
    </div>


 <div class="partialContents comiclist" data-url="@Url.Action("LoadAlphabetBook2", "book", new { delimiters = "e;;;f;;;g;;;h", keywords = "E - H", startLetter = "E", categoryIds = new List<int> { Model.categoryId } })">
 </div>
```

Script:

```
 var site = site || {};
site.baseUrl = site.baseUrl || "";

$(document).ready(function (e) {

    // locate each partial section.
    // if it has a URL set, load the contents into the area.

    $(".partialContents").each(function(index, item) {
        var url = site.baseUrl + $(item).data("url");

        if (url && url.length > 0) {

            $(item).load(url);

        }
    });
});
```

a controller

```
public ActionResult LoadAlphabetBook2(string delimiters, string keywords, string startLetter, List<int> categoryIds = null)
    {
       ......


    }
```

the controller get all parameters correctly except categoryIds. In fact, it tries to load:

/book/LoadAlphabetBook2?delimiters=%23%3B%3B%3B0%3B%3B%3B1%3B%3B%3B2%3B%3B%3B3%3B%3B%3B4%3B%3B%3B5%3B%3B%3B6%3B%3B%3B7%3B%3B%3B8%3B%3B%3B9&keywords=0%20-%209&startLetter=0&categoryIds=System.Int32%5B%5D

How can I get it to work properly passing a list like that instead of a new int[]

Comment: You could alternatively pass all the ids as a string (maybe separated by a delimiter) and then choose to process it in the controller.

Comment: it works but i still dont' know why it doesn't work when passing a list collection.

Comment: Not too sure either. try changing it to this - new List<int> () { Model.categoryId }

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly cast the integer value as string using

```
Model.categoryId.ToString( format ) ;
```

format is optional.